# How to cancel automatic processing of the nillable field in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

When I insert a feature using the WFS, and I only provide geometry attributes. The GeoServer automatically sets the value of the field whose nillable is false to '', instead of reporting an error. But when I use WFS to modify this feature geometry again, this error appears: "Property' start_node_id' is mandatory but no value specified."
The attributes of this field are set as follows:

```
<Property><Name>start_node_id</Name><Value></Value></Property>
```

How can I get GeoServer to report an error when inserting the feature instead of automatically filling in a non-null value?

Comment: If you don't fill a required value then the feature default will be used, it's the client's responsibility to check which attributes are required before sending the request

Comment: I have another question, how to set the field to '' or '   ',  the Geoserver will returns this error: "Property' start_node_id' is mandatory but no value specified." This field has a not NULL limit

Comment: What datastore do you use? PostGIS?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Yes, it's PostGIS